# Correct Threading approach to log analytics

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am about to add analytics into my android application, for that I was thinking of the correct way to go for it. I have researched on some stuffs but wanted an opinion of this community. Basically I simply don't want this analytics related work to be done on the UIThread so I came up with two solutions.

1. use a custom AsyncTask which will post my analytics event to the server. Hence it doesn't interfere with the UIThread.
2. Use a custom Runnable which will be posted to a dedicated handlerThread custom class which will be a kind of singleton class. Hence each of these event can be queued into the dedicated handlerThread and it can loop through the event posted into it.

In my implementation I want to keep the priority of the events thread as low and I have my own server set to keep track of these events. Can someone suggest me which among the two is a good option or I am in a totally wrong direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your actually thinking of doing...
As far as I understand your trying to save and upload logs of app usage to your server, if you want that then there are services that can do that for you like MixPanel.

If your trying to log things and send them to the server on your own - then logging should happen in the same thread of what ever is happening, but the sending should be a different module that is in charge to move those logs when its convenient to the server.

The logs can be sent from every corner and thread in the app using an event bus (like Greenrobot's EventBus) or a singletron module that handles that.

I would advice that the module that would receive these events - would be a Service that works in the background, it should pack logs and uploads them to your server when possible, if you don't need that information in realtime - don't send every log you get immediately.

hope I helped, if not then please explain in more detail :)

> **Update:** check out Google's [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) this library will take care the sending mechanism for you, just know that AsyncTask isn't a good solution anymore, it has many flaws, and as a rule it's always better to send any type of communication on a different Thread then the UI Thread, I'd recommend you do that on a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) dedicated for that or a [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the MixPanel and don't want to use it. I have already created the server which can do all the related processing. Events are captured from the main thread and I do want to send them to the server in a separate thread. The internal class for sending the data have been coded in a way that it accumulates the event and sends the event only when device is either using internet or has reached the threshold. 

My query is regarding what would be the ideal way to send those events. Which threading technique should I use?

Comment: Aight just updated my answer, I understand you already created the logic, so I'll advice you to use a library that is dedicated for that purpose :)